# searching linked list for match

Tags: java

I am trying to search a linked list for a match but am always getting false. Here is my code:

List is filled infile is

```
 try
        {
            BufferedReader infile =
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\videoDat.txt")); .....

       public static void createVideoList(BufferedReader infile,
                                       VideoList videoList)
                                       throws IOException
    {
        String  title;
        String  star1;
        String  star2;
        String  producer;
        String  director;
        String  productionCo;
        int   InStock;



        title = infile.readLine();
 //If the title exists then there is the rest
        while ((title=infile.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Fill Linked list
          star1=infile.readLine();
          star2=infile.readLine();
          producer=infile.readLine();
          director=infile.readLine();
          productionCo=infile.readLine();
          InStock=infile.read();
          VideoElement MovieObject=new VideoElement();
          MovieObject.setVideoInfo(title,star1,star2,producer,
          director,productionCo,InStock);
            videoList.addToList(MovieObject);
            title=infile.readLine();
        }//end while
    }//end createVideoList
```

Search using equals method:

```
public boolean searchVideoList(String title)
{

    for(VideoElement x:VideoList)
    {
        if(x.equals(title))
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
        return false;


}//end searchVideoList
```

calling search from main method:

```
System.out.print("Enter the title: ");
                        title = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println();
                        if(videoList.searchVideoList(title)==true)
                            System.out.println("Title found.");
                        else
                            System.out.println("Video not in store.");
                        break;
```

Sorry I didnt even realize it was using the overided equals method from VideoElement which was provided for us by the teacher:

```
  public boolean equals(DataElement otherElement)
    {
        VideoElement temp = (VideoElement) otherElement;
        return (videoTitle.compareTo(temp.videoTitle) == 0);
    }
```

I am always getting the video not in store because the searchvideolist always returns false at the end. But if I remove that it tells me I need to return something.. What to do..

Comment: you should have two backslashes here:
try { BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\videoDat.txt")); .

Comment: I actually do.. NOt sure why or how I didnt copy them..

Comment: In the above code you are using VideoElement.equals method. So the questions are: (1.) Have you overridden the equals method ? (2.)Why are you not using a comparator here ?

Comment: edited my post to show the equals method in VideoElement. I didnt realize it was calling it from there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is VideoElement extends String in any way?
2. How is the equals() method implemented in VideoElement ? -> You should know that equals is used to compare to Objects of the same type, so unless VideoElement and String are the same you would get false.

try changing your method to something like:
 for(VideoElement x:VideoList)
    {
        if(x.getTitle().equals(title))
        {
             ...
        }

Answer (score 0):

Does your file `C:\videoDat.txt` contains inputs(title, star1, star2, producer etc.) terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed. 
Please ensure this as you are using `BufferedReader.readLine()` because it reads a line of text.

Moreover in your following code:

```
for(VideoElement x:VideoList)
{
    if(x.equals(title))
    {
        return true;
    }
    .....
```

You are comparing a `VideoElement` object `x` with a `String` `title`. Have you tried correcting that?

Comment: Try calling title.trim() method before adding the title to the MovieObject. This might work for the comparison.

Comment: I ended up fixing it by using a variable and returning that variable instead

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it like so:

```
boolean videoSearch(String title){
    VideoElement temp = new VideoElement();
        boolean found = false;
         for(ListIterator<VideoElement> Vitr = VideoList.listIterator();Vitr.hasNext();){
            temp=Vitr.next();
              if(temp.checkTitle(title)){
               //item is found
                  found = true;
                  break;
              }
              else
                  found=false;
         }     

    return found;

    }
```